# Django OAuth2 Toolkit implementation authorization call returns login page html

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0

I am new with the Django OAuth2 Toolkit (and relatively new with Django still) and am trying to implement it with an already existing API (DRF). Up until now, the authorization of the API has worked through a static token that is passed through along with the request. On the website itself, users are able to login and session authentication is enabled.

I installed the toolkit as per the instructions and have created an authorization code application with the 'skip authorization' toggle ticked. I am now trying to access the authorization server with the following URL (as a GET):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=client_1&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/trial&code_challenge=WZRHGrsBESr8wYFZ9sx0tPURuZgG2lmzyvWpwXPKz8U&code_challenge_method=S256&scope=read&client_secret=secret_1
```

When I try to call this (via postman, API or browser) I get back the login page instead of the code as expected. I do not understand why this is happening and how to skip this. Any ideas or help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This happens for different reasons
One is that you have not set the Authorization grant type: to a specified parameter
second is that you did not specify the necessary parameters in the postman

For this case, set the Authorization grant type to resource owner password-based [here you make the changes and save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rm8K.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B740f.png)

After that, make sure that you specify the following parameters in postman [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAI2H.png)